# magento 1.9 where is function getBaseShippingAmount() defined

Tags: magento-1.9, multishipping

in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php there's a method getBaseShippingAmount(); I want to know where is this function defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a field in order table with name base_shipping_amount and getBaseShippingAmount() returns the value of the field for the order object. It is handled by ORM and this is not defined statically something like

```
public function getBaseShippingAmount(){ }
```

This is defined some where dynamically.
for reference you may check this link

```
https://gielberkers.com/magentos-magical-getters-setters-demystified/
```